# How to normalize data of 0s and 1s?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, t-test, data-transformation

the data consists of one 2, so it's not binomial. is there any way to transform it to fit the normal assumptions?
I tried square root and log, both didn't work

Comment: Please say why you think that you need to transform these data into a normal distribution. That really can't be done with this type of count data in any event. If you edit your question to say more about what you are trying to accomplish, then you might get answers that will help you deal with count data, for example modeling with a Poisson distribution.

Comment: I need to compare between two sample data sets. I have one group evaluating two websites on a scale of 1-10 and doing tasks (time and number of errors recorded). The evaluation and the time data sets are normally distributed and I could apply the paired t-test simply. The number of errors, on the other hand, which only included many zeros, 1s, and a 2, isn't normally distributed.

Answer (score 1):

Error rates are a classic example of data that might be modeled with [Poisson distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). Current statistical software packages allow for straightforward modeling of such data as one of several types of [generalized linear models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model). If your data do not match the central assumption of a Poisson model (variance of counts/rates = mean of counts/rates) then negative binomial regression could be applied to such count data. This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) covers both Poisson and negative binomial regressions.